# iOS app crashes upon tapping button to add new Row to a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating an iOS app using Swift to help me keep track of assignments for school using a `UITableView`. However, upon tapping the add button, when it tries to add the new row, the app crashes. I've watched countless tutorials from Brian Voong, Sean Allen, Kilo Loco, etc., and read the tutorials and documentation from Apple and still can't figure out what's wrong. Did I miss something? Did I code something improperly?

Upon the crash, I get the error message:

```
2019-05-06 23:28:58.200728-0500 AssignmentTracker[18768:1102271] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/joshroot/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/45F175C3-2A67-4EB6-9F1D-DE8503AEEDA8/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-05-06 23:28:58.201136-0500 AssignmentTracker[18768:1102271] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2019-05-06 23:29:18.701240-0500 AssignmentTracker[18768:1102271] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3698.103.12/UITableView.m:1821
2019-05-06 23:29:18.713115-0500 AssignmentTracker[18768:1102271] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001116416fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f98dac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111641482 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010f3db927 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 194
    4   UIKitCore                           0x000000011aad86a7 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 8315
    5   UIKitCore                           0x000000011aaf3e6f -[UITableView endUpdates] + 74
    6   AssignmentTracker                   0x000000010f0900e1 $s17AssignmentTracker14ViewControllerC9insertRow10assignmentyAA0A0C_tF + 1169
    7   AssignmentTracker                   0x000000010f08fb6b $s17AssignmentTracker14ViewControllerC15addButtonTappedyyF + 6107
    8   AssignmentTracker                   0x000000010f08fc34 $s17AssignmentTracker14ViewControllerC15addButtonTappedyyFTo + 36
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000011a8de204 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a333c19 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a333f36 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a332eec -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 583
    13  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a916eee -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2547
    14  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a9185d2 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4079
    15  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a8f6d16 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a9c7293 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3232
    17  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a9c9bb9 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5911
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001115a8be1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001115a8463 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001115a2b1f __CFRunLoopRun + 1231
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001115a2302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000115ad82fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    23  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a8dcba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    24  AssignmentTracker                   0x000000010f0920ab main + 75
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112a49541 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The code in - 
ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit;

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var assignments: [Assignment] = [Assignment]();

    @IBOutlet weak var assignmentsTable: UITableView!;
    @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: DoneButton!;
    @IBOutlet weak var assignmentNameField: UITextField!;
    @IBOutlet weak var assignmentDateAssignedField: UITextField!;
    @IBOutlet weak var assignmentDueDateField: UITextField!;
    @IBOutlet weak var assignmentWeightOfAssignmentField: UITextField!;

    var textFields: [UITextField] = [];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        textFields =
        [
            assignmentNameField,
            assignmentDateAssignedField,
            assignmentDueDateField,
            assignmentWeightOfAssignmentField
        ];

        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside);

        Util.setupViewControllerSytles(fields: textFields, viewController: self);
    }

    @objc func addButtonTapped() {
        doneButton.shake();

        let isDataValid: Bool = ValidationUtil.isValidData(viewController: self, name: assignmentNameField.text!, dueDate: assignmentDueDateField.text!, dateAssigned: assignmentDateAssignedField.text!, assignmentWeight: assignmentWeightOfAssignmentField.text!);

        if (isDataValid) {
            insertRow(assignment: Assignment(name: assignmentNameField.text!, dueDate: assignmentDueDateField.text!, assignedDate: assignmentDateAssignedField.text!, assignmentWeight: Double(assignmentWeightOfAssignmentField.text!)!));
        }
    }

    func insertRow(assignment: Assignment) {
        assignments.append(assignment);

        let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: assignments.count - 1, section: 0);

        assignmentsTable.beginUpdates();
        assignmentsTable.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom);
        assignmentsTable.endUpdates();

        Util.cleanUp(fields: textFields);
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true);

        return false;
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return assignments.count;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let assignment = assignments[indexPath.row];

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AssignmentCell") as! AssignmentCell;
        Util.setupAssignmentCell(cell: cell, assignment: assignment);

        return cell;
    }
}
```

The setupAssignmentCell function

```
static func setupAssignmentCell(cell: AssignmentCell, assignment: Assignment) {
        cell.assignmentNameLabel.text = "Name: \(assignment.getName())";
        cell.assignmentDueDateLabel.text = "Due Date: \(assignment.getDueDate())";
        cell.assignmentAssignedDateLabel.text = "Assigned: \(assignment.getAssignedDate())";
        cell.assignmentWeightLabel.text = "Weight (%): \(assignment.getAssignmentWeight())";
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated but you don't need semicolons (`;`) in Swift.

Comment: Are you sure you set the `dataSource` property of `assignmentsTable`? Your code looks right but if the `dataSource` isn't set, it would explain your issue.

Comment: It ended up being that I did forget  set the delegate and data source equal to self

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the problem is caused by updating the `assignments` array before calling `beginUpdates` function.

So my suggestion solution would be to change the `assignments` array after calling `beginUpdates`, like the following:

```
assignmentsTable.beginUpdates();
assignments.append(assignment);
let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: assignments.count - 1, section: 0);
assignmentsTable.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom);
assignmentsTable.endUpdates();
```

Comment: I have made the edits you suggested, but to no avail. I still get the same crash.

Comment: The calls to `begin/endUpdates()` are not necessary.